# Android Application using Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am planning to build an application that connects to a BLE based device/devices which will give me some basic health reading like SPO2, Blood Pressure, Glucose Monitors, weight etc.

I know that there are many Bluetooth based devices available in the market today. But I want to know how I can use them in my application. Will I have to integrate different SDK(dont know if there are any) for every device I want the readings from?

It would be really helpful if I could get some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth Low Energy peripherals offer their Data in Services which themselves contain at least one characteristic. These allow reading and/or writing data.

The manufacturers of such devices can build their own protocol for data transmission or use one of the pre-specified services offered by the Bluetooth SIG. [This list](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) contains the specification and documentation for all of them. Some will be interesting to you, the [Heart Rate Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/heart-rate-service-1-0/) for example.

The documentation contains information about the UUIDs used for the service and the characteristics as well as the required data structure and communication protocol.

Your app should support these in order to allow the usage of BLE devices from different manufacturers.